# sharing failed, in api 23, only failed is for whatsapp, after selecting whatsapp from chooser, it returns back to sharer page

Tags: android, android-sharing

except whatsapp, my app is sharing content to all other application like hike hangout mail, messenger etc..
my compile sdk and target sdk is 23

this is my code

```
if (url.startsWith("share://")) {
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri requestUrl = Uri.parse(url);
            String pContent = requestUrl.toString().split("share://")[1];
            String pasteData = pContent+"";
            share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pasteData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setMargin(50,50);
            toast.show();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String [] parts = pasteData.split("<br />");
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                String part = parts[i];
                sb.append(part);
                sb.append('\n');
            }
            share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (Serializable) sb);
            share.setType("*/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share On"));
            return true;
```

let me clear, this code is working (sharing content) fine for all other application but not in whatsapp

my logcat error

```
    07-29 12:13:20.068 560-578/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity: +392ms (total +21s340ms)
07-29 12:13:29.337 560-1486/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=*/* flg=0xb080001 cmp=com.whatsapp/.ContactPicker clip={*/* T: first line content 
                                                  second line content 
                                                  thired line content
                                                  fourth line content
                                                 } (has extras)} from uid 10281 on display 0
07-29 12:13:29.609 9651-9674/com.example.app I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
07-29 12:13:29.609 9651-9674/com.example.app I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
07-29 12:13:29.609 9651-9674/com.example.app I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
07-29 12:13:29.678 30472-30703/? I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
07-29 12:13:29.678 30472-30703/? I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
07-29 12:13:29.678 30472-30703/? I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
07-29 12:13:29.684 560-572/? I/memtrack_graphic: graphic_memtrack_get_memory match 4:      ion_mm_heap 30448  7864320  11 c3f0dc40 de902b00
                                                  : 30448 30448 7864320 11 714938
07-29 12:13:29.716 560-569/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 60007(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 5(100KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 28MB/42MB, paused 2.514ms total 199.165ms
07-29 12:13:37.046 21901-22266/? I/ClearcutLoggerApiImpl: disconnect managed GoogleApiClient
```

Comment: Have you seen - https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012 ?

Comment: yes , i used intent method to integrate , as you can see in my code .

Comment: Please check it carefully. Whatsup doesn't support way how you share content.

Comment: i modified as per documentation , but still same problem, i think its the matter of sdk, api23 api 22 issue, please suggest with advanced answers, thanks in adv..

Comment: Probably you just have different version of whatsup on different devices. Something like that.

Comment: yes i got the answer

Answer (score 1):

i just got the answer
i just changed

```
share.setType("text/plain");
```

instead of `share.setType("*/*");`

**full code as follow**
`if (url.startsWith("share://")) {
                Uri requestUrl = Uri.parse(url);
                String pContent = requestUrl.toString().split("share://")[1];
                // pContent = firstWord <br /> secondWord <br /> ThirdWord
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pContent,          Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setMargin(50,50);
                toast.show();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String [] parts = pContent.split("<br />");
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                    String part = parts[i];
                    sb.append(part);
                    sb.append('\n');
                }
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (Serializable) sb);
                share.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share On"));
                return true;`