# Android Studio sharing mp3-sound from my raw directory via whatsapp through my app

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, whatsapp

I'd like to share a mp3-file via WhatsApp, using the `ACTION_SEND` method on an intent. Problem is it will not work. The intent works perfectly fine, it opens whatsapp and allows me to select any chat I want. So I select one (still no problem) and click <kbd>send</kbd> and this is where the trouble starts.

I'm getting a pop-up message stating:

***sharing not succesfull, please try again.*** (translated from German)
Code:

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.lmlc.BeckenbauerSoundboard/raw/s01.mp3")); //myuri
    shareIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, textMsgBoxSendMp3));
```

I really hope someone can help me with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, The only thing that I can suggest is to check these options:

1. Make your package name is correct, it's better to copy it from Menifest.
2. Make the file name you given is correct and file exists in the raw folder.
3. WhatsApp has a file size limit, make sure your file size doesn't exceed from that size.
4. Try this code to create URI:

   Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.raw.s01.mp3);

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score -1):

you need to define the MIME type!! I had a similar problem sharing intents on WhatsApp, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695090/sharing-failed-please-try-again-only-in-whatsapp) helped me !! Hopefully will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Many apps will not know what to do with an `android.resource` `Uri`. You will have better luck copying that data to a file, then using `FileProvider` to make it available to other apps.