# Android sharing failed please try again in whatsapp,telegram

Tags: android, android-intent

this is the uri of image that i'm trying to share

**/storage/emulated/0/CR7/ImageApr 21, 2018 6:40:00 PM.jpeg**

on click redirected to package whatever I select whatsapp,telegram but getting error "sharing failed please try again"

```
rl_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(checkPermissions()) {
            Uri uri5 = Uri.parse(myuri);
            Intent t = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            t.setType("image/*");
            t.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri5);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(t, "Share Image"));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get uri by using `Uri uri5 = Uri.parse(myuri);` on android 8.0 and above , you have to use file provider in your application to get uri for a file, also you need to add `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to your share intent, then only the third application can get access to the file

for sample 
res->xml->provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

create dummy class which extends FileProcider in our case GenericFileProvider.java

```
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
public class GenericFileProvider extends FileProvider {
}
```

in your manifest.xml add these lines inside application tag

```
<provider
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

now you can get Uri for File using the bellow code in your application

```
Uri screenshotUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(SelectedImageActivity1.this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
```

Comment: thank you for your valuable time and for this nice explanation thank you so much :)

Comment: Is this the only solution?